# Double receive 0.00 when empty field in JSF is submitted

Tags: jsf-2

People i need receive an null when empty field is submited with JSF:

my class:

```
@RequestScoped
@ManagedBean(name = "teste")
public class Teste {

    private Double valor;

    public Double getValor() {
        return valor;
    }

    public void setValor(Double valor) {
        this.valor = valor;
    }

}
```

and my edit text element:

```
<h:inputText value = "#{teste.nota}" converter="notaConverter">
<h:inputText>
```

my converter:

```
@FacesConverter(forClass = Long.class, value = "notaConverter")
public class NotaConverter implements Converter {

    public NotaConverter() {}

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, Object value) {
        return value == null ? null : value.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, String value) {
        if (value == null || value.isEmpty()) return null;
        Double valor = new Double(value);

        return valor;
    }

}
```

but when set of my managed bean is called i receive an '0.00' value.. WHY?

Answer (score 0):

Add to web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```